# Image to be placed to take right:0px, but does not take

Tags: jquery, css

I have a text in the div, and adjacently an image.  I want the image to be at the end of sentence,ie., `right=0`.  But the image is always placed at the end of the sentence.

This is my code.

```
<div id='xi' class='xc'>Text comes here and can be anything and any length<img src='images/QuestionExpandArrow.jpg'  id='QuestionExpandArrow'></div>
```

I want the image at the extreme right of the sentence.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

Apply `float:right` to the image itself (via separate stylesheet, [not inline `style` attribute](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle)). You will also need to have the image [come before the sentence in HTML](http://phrogz.net/CSS/understandingfloats.html).

```
<head>
  ...
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    #QuestionExpandArrow { float:right }
  </style>
</head><body>
  ...
  <div id='xi' class='xc'>
    <img src='images/QuestionExpandArrow.jpg'  id='QuestionExpandArrow'>
    Text comes here and can be anything and any length
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: it goes to the right though, but it looks like as if right decrements by 10px. It has to be next to the text, as its in a do-while loop

Comment: It has to be next to the text, as its in a do-while loop

Comment: @Jean Please read the second link in my answer above. Floated content must come before the content it is to float next to if you want to use the start position of that content as the float indicator. The fact that it is in a "do-while" loop doesn't change anything about the requirements of HTML and CSS. Fix your code to emit the content you want and need.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the image in a span with a "float:right;" style (or with a class that floats right)?

```
<div id='xi' class='xc'>Text comes here and can be anything and any length<span style="float:right"><img alt="alt" src='images/QuestionExpandArrow.jpg'  id='QuestionExpandArrow' /></span></div>
```

Comment: it goes to the right though, but it looks like as if right decrements by 10px

Comment: That could be because of a style setting in the div, or on the body, or on spans or images generally - if you don't use any other styles it will work.  So you need to look at the impact of any stylesheets being used.

Comment: It has to be next to the text, as its in a do-while loop

Answer (score 1):

Put the image before the text like this,

```
<div id='xi' class='xc'><img src='images/QuestionExpandArrow.jpg'  id='QuestionExpandArrow'/>Text comes here and can be anything and any length</div>
```

Then in your css add #QuestionExpandArrow { float:right; } and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by putting position:absolute